# How to find which amazon login matches a specific ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have multiple amazon accounts.  I have an ec2 instance I've created and am able to RDP into it...

I logged into all of my amazon accounts (that i can remember) and all of them say "0 instances running"... which is bizarre.

**How can I know for sure which aws login is for that specific instance?**

Comment: Do you have your console set to the correct region?

Comment: @datasage - oh, duhh. good call.

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, why do you have multiple AWS accounts? Why did you choose to do that instead of leveraging IAM users under a single account?

Answer (score 0):

As @datasage pointed out. It looks like the aws control panel only shows by region.
I had to go through each region to find it.

(menu in upper right corner)

[image]